# Jquery Datepicker select multiple date ranges in one calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

My requirement is to allow user to select multiple date ranges in a single calendar, also previous date selections should not be allowed to change. How is this possible? Below is the code and link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9szz0fdg/12/)

**HTML**

```
<p>from</p>
<input type="text" class="spromotion-input-inbody spromotion-input-datepick" id="sproid-bookingcondition-datefrom">
<p>to</p>
<input type="text" class="spromotion-input-inbody spromotion-input-datepick" id="sproid-bookingcondition-dateto">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#sproid-bookingcondition-datefrom" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#sproid-bookingcondition-dateto" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });

    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }
  } );
```

Comment: Where's the problem here? What do you mean by multiple date ranges?

Comment: by default we can only select one date range, the requirements is to select multiple date ranges on a single calendar.

Answer (score 3):

Please check this might solve your issue.

```js
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
    $('input[name="daterange"]').change(function(){
      $(this).val();
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <input class="pull-right" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/15/2020 - 02/15/2010">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not something the datepicker plugin is able to do out of the box. You will need some custom JavaScript to enable this.

I found a way which gets close to what you want using the `onSelect` and `beforeShowDay` events. It maintains its own array of selected dates, so unfortunately doesn't integrate with a textbox showing the current date, etc. I'm just using it as an inline control, and I can then query the array for the currently selected dates.

The only thing you would need to alter about this code is grouping every two dates into ranges, but there are multiple ways to do that depending on your desired UX. Personally, I would just group every two dates as a range in the order the user selects. Then if they remove a date from any range, the entire range is removed (that is not coded here, you will need to add that).

Here is my code:

```
<script>
// Maintain array of dates
var dates = new Array();

function addDate(date) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(date, dates) < 0) 
        dates.push(date);
}

function removeDate(index) {
    dates.splice(index, 1);
}

// Adds a date if we don't have it yet, else remove it
function addOrRemoveDate(date) {
    var index = jQuery.inArray(date, dates);
    if (index >= 0) 
        removeDate(index);
    else 
        addDate(date);
    }

// Takes a 1-digit number and inserts a zero before it
function padNumber(number) {
var ret = new String(number);
if (ret.length == 1) 
    ret = "0" + ret;
    return ret;
}

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            addOrRemoveDate(dateText);
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            // months and days are inserted into the array in the form, e.g "01/01/2009", but here the format is "1/1/2009"
            var month = padNumber(date.getMonth() + 1);
            var day = padNumber(date.getDate());
            // This depends on the datepicker's date format
            var dateString = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            var gotDate = jQuery.inArray(dateString, dates);
            if (gotDate >= 0) {
                // Enable date so it can be deselected. Set style to be highlighted
                return [true, "ui-state-highlight"];
            }
            // Dates not in the array are left enabled, but with no extra style
            return [true, ""];
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gydL0epa/

Answer (score 0):

As others already suggested, my [MultiDatesPicker](https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/) comes close to what your need. It already allows [single range selection](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#demo-days-range), so you could fork that plugin and edit/improve it to allow *multiple ranges* selection.

A quick and dirty solution would be to comment out [the line where the array of selected dates gets reset](https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/blob/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js#L359).

Answer (score 0):

I think this Multi datepicker will help you to solve your problem.

```js
$('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<div id="mdp-demo"></div>
```

Comment: **This is Useful for Me With Multiple Dates (Custom) Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the daterangepicker.

Add these two lines to your daterangepicker.min.js file.

```
var oldStartDate_list = new Array();
var oldEndDate_list = new Array();
```

Now we have to add some code to some functions. Just look at the "ADD THE FOLLOWING CODE" lines

ClickDate function:

```
 clickDate: function(t) {
        if (R(t.target).hasClass("available")) {
            var e = R(t.target).attr("data-title"),
                a = e.substr(1, 1),
                i = e.substr(3, 1),
                s = R(t.target).parents(".calendar").hasClass("left") ? this.leftCalendar.calendar[a][i] : this.rightCalendar.calendar[a][i];
            if (this.endDate || s.isBefore(this.startDate, "day")) {
                if (this.timePicker) {
                    var n = parseInt(this.container.find(".left .hourselect").val(), 10);
                    if (!this.timePicker24Hour) "PM" === (h = this.container.find(".left .ampmselect").val()) && n < 12 && (n += 12), "AM" === h && 12 === n && (n = 0);
                    var r = parseInt(this.container.find(".left .minuteselect").val(), 10),
                        o = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find(".left .secondselect").val(), 10) : 0;
                    s = s.clone().hour(n).minute(r).second(o)
                }
                this.endDate = null, this.setStartDate(s.clone())
            } else if (!this.endDate && s.isBefore(this.startDate)) this.setEndDate(this.startDate.clone());
            else {
                if (this.timePicker) {
                    var h;
                    n = parseInt(this.container.find(".right .hourselect").val(), 10);
                    if (!this.timePicker24Hour) "PM" === (h = this.container.find(".right .ampmselect").val()) && n < 12 && (n += 12), "AM" === h && 12 === n && (n = 0);
                    r = parseInt(this.container.find(".right .minuteselect").val(), 10), o = this.timePickerSeconds ? parseInt(this.container.find(".right .secondselect").val(), 10) : 0;
                    s = s.clone().hour(n).minute(r).second(o)
                }
                this.setEndDate(s.clone()), this.autoApply && (this.calculateChosenLabel(), this.clickApply())
            
                //ADD THE FOLLOWING CODE//////////
                oldStartDate_list.push(this.startDate);
                oldEndDate_list.push(this.endDate);
                //////////////////////////////////

            }
            this.singleDatePicker && (this.setEndDate(this.startDate), this.timePicker || this.clickApply()), this.updateView(), t.stopPropagation()
        }
    },
```

renderCalendar function:

```
  renderCalendar: function(t) {     
        var e, a = (e = "left" == t ? this.leftCalendar : this.rightCalendar).month.month(),
            i = e.month.year(),
            s = e.month.hour(),
            n = e.month.minute(),
            r = e.month.second(),
            o = H([i, a]).daysInMonth(),
            h = H([i, a, 1]),
            l = H([i, a, o]),
            c = H(h).subtract(1, "month").month(),
            d = H(h).subtract(1, "month").year(),
            m = H([d, c]).daysInMonth(),
            f = h.day();
        (e = []).firstDay = h, e.lastDay = l;
        for (var p = 0; p < 6; p++) e[p] = [];
        var u = m - f + this.locale.firstDay + 1;
        m < u && (u -= 7), f == this.locale.firstDay && (u = m - 6);
        for (var D = H([d, c, u, 12, n, r]), g = (p = 0, 0), y = 0; p < 42; p++, g++, D = H(D).add(24, "hour")) 0 < p && g % 7 == 0 && (g = 0, y++), e[y][g] = D.clone().hour(s).minute(n).second(r), D.hour(12), this.minDate && e[y][g].format("YYYY-MM-DD") == this.minDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") && e[y][g].isBefore(this.minDate) && "left" == t && (e[y][g] = this.minDate.clone()), this.maxDate && e[y][g].format("YYYY-MM-DD") == this.maxDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") && e[y][g].isAfter(this.maxDate) && "right" == t && (e[y][g] = this.maxDate.clone());
        "left" == t ? this.leftCalendar.calendar = e : this.rightCalendar.calendar = e;
        var k = "left" == t ? this.minDate : this.startDate,
            b = this.maxDate,
            C = ("left" == t ? this.startDate : this.endDate, this.locale.direction, '<table class="table-condensed">');
        C += "<thead>", C += "<tr>", (this.showWeekNumbers || this.showISOWeekNumbers) && (C += "<th></th>"), k && !k.isBefore(e.firstDay) || this.linkedCalendars && "left" != t ? C += "<th></th>" : C += '<th class="prev available"><span></span></th>';
        var v = this.locale.monthNames[e[1][1].month()] + e[1][1].format(" YYYY");
        if (this.showDropdowns) {
            for (var Y = e[1][1].month(), w = e[1][1].year(), P = b && b.year() || this.maxYear, x = k && k.year() || this.minYear, M = w == x, S = w == P, I = '<select class="monthselect">', B = 0; B < 12; B++)(!M || B >= k.month()) && (!S || B <= b.month()) ? I += "<option value='" + B + "'" + (B === Y ? " selected='selected'" : "") + ">" + this.locale.monthNames[B] + "</option>" : I += "<option value='" + B + "'" + (B === Y ? " selected='selected'" : "") + " disabled='disabled'>" + this.locale.monthNames[B] + "</option>";
            I += "</select>";
            for (var A = '<select class="yearselect">', L = x; L <= P; L++) A += '<option value="' + L + '"' + (L === w ? ' selected="selected"' : "") + ">" + L + "</option>";
            v = I + (A += "</select>")
        }
        if (C += '<th colspan="5" class="month">' + v + "</th>", b && !b.isAfter(e.lastDay) || this.linkedCalendars && "right" != t && !this.singleDatePicker ? C += "<th></th>" : C += '<th class="next available"><span></span></th>', C += "</tr>", C += "<tr>", (this.showWeekNumbers || this.showISOWeekNumbers) && (C += '<th class="week">' + this.locale.weekLabel + "</th>"), R.each(this.locale.daysOfWeek, function(t, e) {
                C += "<th>" + e + "</th>"
            }), C += "</tr>", C += "</thead>", C += "<tbody>", null == this.endDate && this.maxSpan) {
            var E = this.startDate.clone().add(this.maxSpan).endOf("day");
            b && !E.isBefore(b) || (b = E)
        }
        for (y = 0; y < 6; y++) {

            C += "<tr>", this.showWeekNumbers ? C += '<td class="week">' + e[y][0].week() + "</td>" : this.showISOWeekNumbers && (C += '<td class="week">' + e[y][0].isoWeek() + "</td>");
            for (g = 0; g < 7; g++) {
                var W = [];
                
                e[y][g].isSame(new Date, "day") && W.push("today"), 5 < e[y][g].isoWeekday() && W.push("weekend"), e[y][g].month() != e[1][1].month() && W.push("off"), this.minDate && e[y][g].isBefore(this.minDate, "day") && W.push("off", "disabled"), b && e[y][g].isAfter(b, "day") && W.push("off", "disabled"), this.isInvalidDate(e[y][g]) && W.push("off", "disabled"), e[y][g].format("YYYY-MM-DD") == this.startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") && W.push("active", "start-date"), null != this.endDate && e[y][g].format("YYYY-MM-DD") == this.endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD") && W.push("active", "end-date"), null != this.endDate && e[y][g] > this.startDate && e[y][g] < this.endDate && W.push("in-range"); 
                
                //ADD THE FOLLOWING CODE//////////
                for (var osd_i = 0; osd_i < oldStartDate_list.length; osd_i++) {
                if(!W.includes("start-date") && !W.includes("end-date") && 
                e[y][g].format("YYYY-MM-DD") == oldStartDate_list[osd_i].format("YYYY-MM-DD")) {
                W.push("active", "start-date")  
                if(W.includes("in-range"))
                W.splice(W.indexOf("in-range"),1);}
                if(!W.includes("start-date") && !W.includes("end-date") && 
                e[y][g].format("YYYY-MM-DD") == oldEndDate_list[osd_i].format("YYYY-MM-DD")) {
                W.push("active", "end-date")    
                if(W.includes("in-range"))
                W.splice(W.indexOf("in-range"),1);}
                if(!W.includes("start-date") && !W.includes("end-date") && !W.includes("in-range") && 
                e[y][g] > oldStartDate_list[osd_i] && e[y][g] < oldEndDate_list[osd_i])
                W.push("in-range");} 
                //////////////////////////////////
                
                var O = this.isCustomDate(e[y][g]);
                !1 !== O && ("string" == typeof O ? W.push(O) : Array.prototype.push.apply(W, O));
                var N = "",
                    j = !1;
                for (p = 0; p < W.length; p++) N += W[p] + " ", "disabled" == W[p] && (j = !0);
                j || (N += "available"), C += '<td class="' + N.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") + '" data-title="r' + y + "c" + g + '">' + e[y][g].date() + "</td>"
            }
            C += "</tr>"
        }
        C += "</tbody>", C += "</table>", this.container.find(".calendar." + t + " .calendar-table").html(C) 
        
    },
```

clickCancel function:

```
 clickCancel: function(t) {             
            //ADD THE FOLLOWING CODE//////////                  
            oldStartDate_list.length = 0;
            oldEndDate_list.length = 0;
            //////////////////////////////////
        this.startDate = this.oldStartDate, this.endDate = this.oldEndDate; this.hide(), this.element.trigger("cancel.daterangepicker", this)
    },
```

Now you should be able to select multiple ranges: [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqJ6y.png)

I used the min js and first chased it through a beautifier. You could of course also use the normal daterangepicker.js which is well, clearly more readable.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/pepper-ginder-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="fromDate" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#fromDate').multiDatesPicker();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can download the js file from the link https://sourceforge.net/projects/multidatespickr/

Comment: this solution is applicable for single date selection multiple times but not range of date selection.